# Why are monitors only at neck height by default?

Tags: ergonomics, industrial-design, hardware

Most computer monitors are too low. Almost everybody, at least once in their lives, has put a pack of printing paper, a cardboard box, or something else under their monitors stand to bring it to an acceptable height.

Why is the default height for computer monitor stands so low?

Comment: I'll tell you why mine is lifted up on a stand - it's because I don't want to see the person on the desk opposite me. Puts me off!

Comment: I rarely have problems with monitors being too low. Desks on the other hand....

Comment: I'm pretty short so i've never had an issue with the monitor sitting to low however my spouse is another story. He's tall and ended up mounting his monitors on stands that he is comfortable with. Maybe it would be a good issue to identify within monitor manufacturers to resolve.

Comment: Might depend on the table layout, it's different if the keyboard is under or on the table.

Comment: Monitors are typically at shin-height, at best. Not sure this is a valid question. I think you're perhaps asking why monitor stands designed for desks are not adjustable to a higher level than you prefer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a UX question.

Comment: I would say that this question relates very strongly to Ergonomics which, given the current organization of StackExchange sites, falls under the UX umbrella.

Comment: Because the guys who set the standards are all old and have trifocals, and they can't see the monitor clearly through the top 1/3rd of their glasses.

Comment: I agree with ***@DA01***, in my opinion, there's nothing that can be gained here other than conjecture, and that in-and-of-itself makes it primarily opinion based which is a _valid_ close reason.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey asking what the best ergonomic height for a monitor would be a valid question. But this one is lacking in citations and is more open to speculation.

Comment: @DA01 - the question could do with improving, but I did not agree with the blanket rationale of "this is not UX".

Comment: @DA01 glad you announce your intent... I was wondering what you were thinking

Comment: @DA01 Maybe that's why many monitor lovers love to pick up their monitors http://www.catersnews.com/uploadedimages/14082012519309905.jpg

Comment: Because there are people out there using monitors who are less than 6 feet tall. I would like to add, for the benefit of any industry designers out there, that us little ones also like to drive cars, access the top shelf in the supermarket, watch films in cinemas and many other things, and it would be nice if things weren't all designed for beanpoles.

Comment: Don't know if this was mentioned, but maybe because the monitor requires a smaller box when lowered, so it makes sense from a logistics standpoint.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because you can always put some additional stand, but it might be really hard to "cut" the default one :) Low fixed stand seems to be universal and pretty cheap solution.

[image]

Usually, better stand is a good motivation to pay more.

[image]

Comment: +1 for economic reason. I'd add that some people still put their monitor on top of a horizontal desktop computer.

Comment: Economy is the reason. I've got a monitor here that allows a 4D motion on its stand (height, declination, inclination, rotation). However, I suppose that it was quite expensive...

Comment: +1 for showing common sense. Placing a too-low monitor higher is much easier than trying to make a too-high monitor lower.

Answer (score 48):

Most often they are actually not too low. According to widely accepted ergonomics guidelines, your eyes should be [inline with the top of the monitor](https://www.osha.gov/SLTC/etools/computerworkstations/checklist.html).

Looking downwards to it is at worst against your preference, looking up to it by even a small amount is really bad for your back and neck. So it is much better to err on the side of it being too low.

Comment: I think I found my own answer with the contrast between the formerly more common "desktop" PC form factor with a monitor placed on top of it, and a monitor directly on top of a desk.

Comment: @Martijn That was common when CRTs were in use, they had smaller stands that TFTs have so I don't think that explanation works.

Comment: @digsrafik here is a link to the research behind UK guidance http://www.hse.gov.uk/msd/dse/rrintro.htm

Comment: "Most often they are actually not too low". I don't agree at all. Taking a standard office chair, desk and monitor, adult population average height and following the sitting guidelines, the top of the monitor is almost always below or way below "the eyes line". Related: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sVuDx.jpg

Comment: @rewobs my monitor as about twice as tall as the one in that picture! it is right in spirit but the proportions are not remotely realistic

Comment: I think those guidelines must have been developed in the days of 17" or smaller monitors.  With a 24" widescreen (Dell U2412, which has a nice height adjustment) my eye level is comfortably about 1/4 - 1/3 down from the top - which means the most frequently used windows on the display fall at a little below eye level.   Which is another adjustment factor: moving the windows on the display.

Comment: Saying it's not realist is ridiculous. I don't know your particular situation, I've mentioned average. For 1.67m height, the distance between the elbows and the eyes is approximately 45-47cm (55cm in my case) according to body proportions. The average monitor nowadays is 19' according to screen resolutions, and here you can take a look at a 19' samsung monitor http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer-images/product/monitors/2012/LS19B150NS-EN/LS19B150NS-EN-85896-0.jpg. You have AT LEAST 10 cm difference with the average and in my case I have near 20cm when sitting roughly straight (I'm 1.84m).

Comment: @JamesRyan As a final proof, I'm leaving a picture of my "not remotely realistic" self. LOL https://scontent-a-mia.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/p320x320/10690175_10205036724173771_8543660107864064047_n.jpg?oh=e0aea6e6a84bc3767d85d74d0e7e8687&oe=5524BB6D . There should be even more difference, but the chair can't reach high enough to place my elbows correctly (at the same line or a little bit above the desk).

Comment: @JamesRyan, can you cite a source that supports your assertion that looking up is worse for your back and neck than looking down is?

Comment: @3nafish https://www.osha.gov/SLTC/etools/computerworkstations/components_monitors.html#Angle

Comment: @rewobs a) your monitor looks about half as tall as mine (roughly the width of a fullsize keyboard in height) b) your elbows do not have to be straight down by your sides like that, your desk is too low.  If I tried to do that the desk literally wouldn't physically fit between my arms and legs.

Comment: @JamesRyan a)Just look up for your monitor model specs for size comparison, photos are not a good tool to evaluate things with precision. What size is your monitor anyway? b) how can you evaluate the opening angle of the elbows from the side perspective? Indeed The desk is too high, or the chair too low, but the desk low? Not at all. If it was higher my forearm would point up, when it should point just a bit down.

Comment: @rewobs because if your feet are flat on the floor, your chair height is a set position.

Comment: @JamesRyan I didn't ask why, I don't get the point of your comment. Other image, this time at home with a higher desk and a 22¨ f.HD monitor. http://bit.ly/1Ld6enQ

Comment: -1; all places I've ever worked at had 90% of the programmers employ two packs of A4 paper, a box or an extra stand underneath all their screens. Maybe those who have 30" screens don't need this, but 19" screens with tall enough stands don't exist.

Comment: @romkyns don't forget that 4:3 screens are significantly taller than widescreen for the same diagonal size.  I think what is common in a given workplace depends a lot on the era of purchase. I use a 24" widescreen, the top is level with my eyes and it is not as high as it can go. Regardless, propping up the monitor on paper may well be common but is a matter of preference rather than avoiding injury. The monitor *could* be used quite easy, depending on lighting, angled up.

Answer (score 29):

### **Making things clear**

The fact is that **the people who care or are aware about the posture and really follow the guidelines are the minority**. Also despite the knowledge people can have about posture, it doesn't imply at all that the will apply it (or do it correctly).

Taking a standard office chair, desk and monitor, adult population average height and **following the sitting guidelines**, the top of the monitor **is almost always** at least below and possible way below "the eyes line".

Particularly talking about monitor height, if you follow the rule of "the eyes in the same line as the top of the monitor" but you are sitting like [this](https://haroldgibbons.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/lens2363832_1231189377computer_man3.jpg), **the rule is meaningless**:
[image]

---

### **Business time:**

So as a monitor building company, **why would you bother in adding costs and making your product more complex and expensive if the majority of potential buyers is not going to appreciate that feature or if that feature is easily replaceable?** I'm not saying that there are no reasons to do it, I'm saying that **it seems that for most companies there are not enough strong reasons to include a good high adjustment feature as a default.**

---

Comment: Your picture is a good example as to why there can't be a 'standard' monitor stand height. A lot of people would consider your desk about 8" too low and would want a much higher desk but with a keyboard tray.

Comment: What's "not remotely realistic" in that picture is not your self, but your tiny little monitor.  And what DA01 said - you should at least be able to cross your legs under the desk without bruising them!

Comment: @DA01 I agree. I think what's discuss here partly is why they don't have a wider height regulation by default (I made my comments about that at the end of my answer). There are other markets (gamers) where for example, a weight or form(grip) customization of the mouse is valuable for a good portion of the clients.

Comment: The w3schools numbers combine external monitors, laptop screens, tablets, and phones; unless they've got a per device class breakout I'm not sure how much I'd give them for any one use case.  [Steam's hardware survey](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey), which is biased the other way (toward higher end systems) has 1920x1080 as 33% and 1366x768 following at 27%.  In both cases I suspect 1366x768 is dominated by laptop screens which are almost all smaller than your 19" screen and universally low if not put on a stand of some sort.

Comment: I agree. Other source where desktop+laptops can be filtered  http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop-resolution-ww-monthly-201301-201412. About 10% is 1920x1080, possible a little more recalculating the % without laptops . Anyway, I've made the clarification that my home's 22" 1920x1080 monitor still leaves around 13/15cm between my eyes' height and the top of the monitor, maybe a 27" could reach my sight line, but that monitor size it's not even close to average for desktop.

Comment: @rewobs I have a good 2" between the top of my legs and the desk, you are barely squeezed under yours.  It is too low and you are too close to the keyboard, your arms should not be hanging by your sides. Its supposed to be the same position as playing a piano, forearm horizontal, top bit of arm slightly diagonal.

Comment: @JamesRyan FYI armrests fits just under, which are at  the very least 1.8" higher than my legs on the sit, so your observation is  wrong just from the start, maybe you are getting confused with the little drawer on the side. I'm close to the keyboard because I had to bring the keyboard back to place the monitor down (because I always have it over a 18cm box). The point of the photo was eyes- top of the monitor relationship.

Comment: @rewobs: First, your w3schools link has screen resolution, which has nothing to do with display size.  I'd also say 1366x768 is pretty low - even my tablet has 1920x1200.  Both my Dell monitors have height adjustment that place the top at eye height or above (at 6', I'm over average height), as does just about every monitor I've seen in various offices & labs.  Bottom line is that while SOME monitors are low, there are plenty that aren't.  If yours is too low for comfort, get a better one!

Comment: @jamesqf First, you are repeating what was said and clarified on the comments above, and you didn't give any justification about your previous statements. "Pretty low" for what porpoise? Are you sure that average users worldwide need more than 1366x768? If you want to go a store and checkout every monitor (as I did with Samsung and Lg 18-24" ones) and asking about the best selling one in the last year and present the data about if they can be adjustable and with what range it'd be great, but your comment doesn't have specific or ascertainable data in any sense.

Comment: @jamesqf "SOME monitors are low, there are plenty that aren't." That doesn't say, prove or justify anything. How low is "low"? Without specs and numbers how can you say what is approximately low? The original question says "Why is the default height for computer monitor stands so low?". Do you think the worldwide majority is using a 22"/24" monitor with adjustable height or that the ones built has BY DEFAULT a considerable height adjustment to suit the majority(supposing that majority follows the posture guidelines correctly)? That could be true just in wonderland.

Comment: @rewobs: On the resolution thing, maybe the porpoise was Flipper :-)  But if you like e.g. being able to read a reasonable amount of text (say a page of an academic paper, or a few editor windows) 1600/1920x1200 is fairly decent.  For the original question, what I'm saying is that it is NOT the default height.  The low/small monitors are one available option, perhaps for those who still put their monitor on top of a desktop PC, or on a shelf.  But it's easy, and common in at least some circles, to find taller ones. (to be continued...)

Comment: @rewobs: As evidence, here's a link to monitors offered by a large online retailer, sorted by best rating: http://www.newegg.com/LCD-LED-Monitors/SubCategory/ID-20?Order=RATING  As best I can tell from the pictures, almost all on the first couple of pages have height adjustment that would bring them well in the ergonomic eye-level range.  If someone chooses a monitor that's different... Well, that's why there's a product range.

Comment: @jamesqf Full HD resolution just to read a paper? It's okay if you have high standards but that's not really necessary, only extra confort, just compare it with a printed paper. I agree that there could be options with height regulations but not in every country and not in every brand/size, also in your example I can see aprox. 1/3 (which it's quite a lot) that have height regulation and remember these are a new generation of monitors. IDK the data from the at least last 3 years from every brand. People don't switch their monitor every year. For a huge amount of jobs 20" it's more than decent.

Comment: @jamesqf Summing up, I agree that in some countries  you can have plenty options, but not in every country and even less in the mid-range size/price ones.
What is big or small, depends on the time and human perception, everything tends to goes bigger, but that's not a valid reason for changing the perception for what's just necessary for everyone or every task. We should get back to the topic of "why are not them all adjustable?". And btw, I'll do any further comment "moving to chat" as SE recommends.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20604/discussion-between-rewobs-and-jamesqf).

Comment: Tell your boss to get a new chair, a new table, a new monitor and some boxes of paper for you. Easy! Ergonomics!

Comment: @armin If you pay attention I have a pile of  boxes 15cm or higher behind the monitor. It was just a photo to illustrate this is a totally possible and common case not my actual setup, I've already mention this in another comments.

Comment: @rewobs I was just being cheeky. Imho there is a **large gap** between what is commonly referred to as "ergonomic standards" and reality - and that gap is getting larger every year.

Answer (score 29):

Speculation.

Monitors used to look like this:

[image]

you put the big computer on your desk, and the tiny monitor sat on top of it - at the correct height. As we tried to make the desk "cleaner", the box went on the ground (or inside the monitor). And so your problem was born.

Answer (score 10):

The issue with ergonomic guidelines similar to that shown [on the Apple website](https://www.apple.com/about/ergonomics/vision.html) is that virtually no one sits like that (contrary to what our school teachers have tried to make us do).  [Almost everyone likes to lean back a bit](http://ergo.human.cornell.edu/DEA3250Flipbook/DEA3250notes/sitting.html), and most office chairs allow for this.  In fact, it is [NOT good for you to sit straight up as a college design professor discovered](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/6187080.stm).

With all that in mind, the reason why the monitor seems too low is that once you lean back even a little bit, your gaze tends to go up, and therefore the monitor no longer is at the right height.  For myself, I like to have my chair tilted back, with a bit of a footrest, and the monitor tilting slightly down.

This is a great example of why designers are starting to look less at ergonomics or best practices and more at behavior and context of use.

Comment: Is there any source you can cite to support your assertion that "almost everyone likes to lean back a bit"?

Comment: Added in a source for that.  It's #6 on this page: http://ergo.human.cornell.edu/DEA3250Flipbook/DEA3250notes/sitting.html

Comment: Also, I suspect that hardly anyone sits in the same position all the time.  Mine even varies depending on just what I'm doing.  I'll sit in anything from leaning back with legs outstretched (good for thinking) to an upright half-lotus (good for intense concentration).

Comment: I love the separated keyboard tray on Apple's ergonomy site. Reminds me of those "no space for your legs" [90s computer desks](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61pLPEbLR8L._SL1000_.jpg).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I missed an answer, but all of the answers seem to be missing a key point: **it is significantly easier to make a monitor taller rather than shorter**. Stacking your monitor on stacks of paper or boxes may seem like an inconvenience, but imagine what would happen if monitors were made taller. I'm nearly certain there would exists some desks in which the previous size monitor was the proper size. Now, the monitor is too high for the set up, which is not easy to remedy. Getting a new desk or chair are the only viable options beside cutting a trench into your desk to hold the monitor.

From a UX perspective, you should always err on the side of the easy to remedy extreme. I've honestly never seen a monitor issue that was not easy to remedy. Being able to simply fix a problem is quality of good UX when large amounts of variability are too be expected.

Comment: @RenatGilmanov answer already mentioned that point. "you can always put some additional stand, but it might be really hard to 'cut' the default one"

Answer (score 2):

***Who says they are "neck height" by default?***

1. What source do you have that supports this claim?
2. You aren't taking into account any of the following:

   - Height of person.
   - Desk (or table) height.
   - Monitor width and height.
   - Monitor stand height (if you have one).
   - Keyboard type, height, and wrist angle.
   - Mouse type, height, and wrist angle.
   - Chair height, position, and angle.

If you take into the account all of the above, nearly every person will have a ***"different default"***.

***That's why you customize everything to ergonomically fit your specific dimensions.***

Nothing else needs to be said.

Comment: In an ideal world everything would be easily adjustable, even your little desk in your economy class flight. The reality is different. People have to cope with non-adjustable products and they have to *share* things.

Comment: Here in the U.S., organizations have to abide by the United States Department of Labor's Occupational Safety and Health Administration ([OSHA](https://www.OSHA.gov)) or suffer the consequences. All you have to do is file a complaint and they will come in and make sure your working environment is legitimately adequate for you. Hence my answer. #1 can't even be proven.  This whole question is based on a logical fallacy.

Answer (score 0):

I have full freedom in where I place my monitors.

The one closest to my keyboard, I want to be *close* to my keyboard. So it is below eye level, the bottom only barely over my hands. This is convenient so I can move my eyes from screen to keyboard easily.

The other I have with about 10% of the screen above my eyes - I can see the screen content without craning my neck up, and everything comfortably in me view when looking straight forwards.

For people with a single monitor, proximity to the keyboard would seem a good driving reason to make the screen lower.

[Edit:

Hrm - someone downvoted? Do they disbelieve that proximity to the keyboard matters from a UX point of view? I am forced to disagree, it matters significantly to me. Perhaps for formally-trained touch-typists who're only ever typing and not regularly moving hands from mouse to keyboard and back, it might not be - the keyboard can even be hidden! But for what I'd argue is the overwhelming majority, the keyboard and mouse are focal parts of the work area, need to be visible, and hence need to be close to the screen.

Even for those with hidden keyboards, I'd argue that the workplace focus should never be directly ahead. Workbenches have never worked like this, neither have drafting tables, nor easels, nor any line of work I can think of. The focal point is usually down from the eyes, somewhere around or just above the hands, since that's what we are used to looking at, and working with.

So for even my highest monitor, the midpoint is about 15 degrees down from eye-level.]

Comment: This reads pretty strangely to me. The idea that someone would want to spend a significant proportion of time looking *at* the mouse or keyboard, rather than looking at the screen where the keystrokes go and the pointer is.

Comment: Watch the eyes of your coworkers for a while. I think you may be surprised. But that wasn't my point - you aren't looking necessarily at your *hands* but at the point in space where your hands would be if you were performing manual labor, because that is the natural space for someone to look at. Looking directly ahead is unnatural and weird.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using computers for about 30 years and have rarely found any position comforable for prolonged use. I've recently (about 4 months ago) changed to using a standing desk. The monitors are now at the right height, my back and shoulders dont ache and I burn more calories standing than sitting down. Its also nicer when people walk up to my desk and I dont have to look up to them as I am already at their level.

Learn to touch type - it will be more comforatble if you are working standing up or sitting down.

Answer (score -1):

**We** use monitors all day without having to look at match paper on our desks.

A lot of people used to (and still do) have to keep moving their eyes from the monitor to paper on the desk.

Also a lot of people are not touch typists, so have to move their eye to the keyboard often.

**If a monitor is two low, someone can put it on books, if it is too height all they can do is return it for a refund.**

Monitors with adjustable stands cost more.....